# Open soft keyboard after Dialog dismiss

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In Android app, we have custom `AppCompatDialog` class and need to **open the soft input method (keyboard) on `EditText` after dialog was dismissed**.

For showing the keyboard, this function is used:

```
fun View.showKeyboard() = context.inputMethodManager?.let {
    // Find the really focused EditText in this root view.
    val focusedView = if (this is ViewGroup) this.findFocus() else this

    it.showSoftInput(focusedView ?: this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

In dialog `OnDismissListener`, when calling this code below in `Fragment`, the code produces the expected outcome like in 70% of cases, but in order to work *always* in emulator and real devices, arbitrary `50ms` delay time was needed to add for `postDelayed`.

```
view?.post {
    binding.input.apply {
        // binding.input is our custom Widget that contains EditText
        requestFocus()
        showKeyboard()
    }
}
```

I would prefer to not have this *magic number* in the codebase and also I'm afraid, this might not work in some Android distributions.

Is there any better proven solution, that will work on most Android versions and vendor specific distributions?

Thanks for any help